# Can a player expose a shielded host to wireless connection?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, sr5-matrix

Let's say there is a computer or server in a room protected by a faraday cage. This makes it so that the player must enter the room in order to access the node, since the Faraday cage prevents wireless signals from passing through.

My players have come up with a method that they think should work to allow a decker to remotely access the information from outside the Faraday cage. They want to directly attach a commlink to the server via a long cable, and then move the commlink outside the Faraday cage.

Is this a sufficient way to work around the limitations that a Faraday cage provides? Would the wired commlink, when moved outside the Faraday cage, provide a wireless access point for the decker? If so... are there any drawbacks / weaknesses to this approach?

The next natural question is... could many commlinks be daisy-chained together to move extend the wired connection farther away?

To be clear, I'm asking if the rules allow for this type of workaround.

Comment: To be clear, are you looking for answers from Shadowrun's published rules, or real-life networking?  In reality, it answer is "Yes".  I've done this very thing when someone setup their network gear in a metal-lined room (unintentionally).

Comment: Yes, I'm wondering if the SR5 rules allow for this.

Comment: Jessa is right, and as drawback I would say that cutting the cable or smashing the commlink and your "tunnel connection" is out. As Kekse said, a program could notice the wire connection and raise an alarm (send some guys to cut/smash), or maybe close the port to the wire connection, like cutting but software made.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  The Commlink has a wired connection to the server.  The Commlink has a wireless connection to the Matrix.  If you hack the Commlink node (or otherwise access it), you can access the server node.  Using the comlink wirelessly is no different than using it "in person"; in fact, you *can't ever* really use it in person because the AR gloves, glasses, trodes, etc. you use to interact with it actually interact with devices that wirelessly broadcast to your link (but that's getting close to outside the rules).  The only issue is the greater potential for Noise, but there are plenty of ways around that.

Note also that this works in real-life and SR4.

As for the daisy chaining extension: yes, that is also possible (Indeed, the bulk of the Matrix is P2P traffic, if I remember correctly) but keep in mind you are creating a network bottleneck when doing this and that if *any* link is compromised the whole scheme is.  This approach has basically no advantage over just using a really long wire, except that the links can use their wireless communication ability to hop over or through physical barriers.  They will basically always be a worse choice that just wiring along to an actual Matrix access point, though.  Also there's no need to daisy chain them (slave them to one another); you can move from one to the other just fine without doing that-- it's default Matrix behavior.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same Idea recently. It should be possible as far as i can see. I don't have acess to the rulebook at the moment to find further information.

However there are some severe drawbacks:

- If there is an enemy decker inside the Host, he could see the connected Commlink as a device. If the Commlink isn't configured correctly, he might even "see" the Matrix outside the cage. He/She would raise the alarm immediately! How he could easily spot it or not needs a deeper look into the rulebook.
- As the cage (a physical iron cage or a cage created by electromagnetic noise) will interfere with any electromagnetic signals, you would definitely need glass fiber cables or another form of non-electric transmission. Placing those might be tricky.
- Of course there can be physical guards patroling the area. Some of them might see the commlink/cables. ->Alarm

Comment: Pretty much all 'wired' communication in Shadowrun is optical, not electric.  Getting and using optical wiring wouldn't be hard; there's probably already some in the walls for lighting tbh.  Otherwise good.